# Wrong dendrogram in Matlab (compared with R)

Tags: r, matlab, linkage, dendrogram

I am trying to make a dendrogram in Matlab based on a dissimilarity matrix X. I converted it into a format that linkage would accept by using `Y=squareform(X)`. I then get the following vector:

```
Y = [0 0 0 0 1.4476 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.7525 0 0 0 0 0 1.9634 11.3676 0 0 0 2.1579 14.4957 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

I tried to plot a dendrogram using complete linkage:

```
dendrogram(linkage(Y,'complete'))
```

and get the following result: 
[image: dendrogram1]

However, when I use the dissimilarity matrix X in R (also with the complete linkage method: `dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(as.dist(X)))` ) I get a completely different dendrogram: 
[image: [dendrogram2][2].]
The dendrogram made with R makes a lot more sense with the input data than the matlab one (as it fits the expected grouping of the used data). 
Any idea why they are so different? And is there a way to reproduce the R dendrogram in matlab?

EDIT: the X matrix:

```
     0         0         0         0         0    1.4476         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.7525
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.9634
     0         0         0         0   11.3676         0         0         0    2.1579
     0         0         0   11.3676         0   14.4957         0         0         0
1.4476         0         0         0   14.4957         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0    1.7525    1.9634    2.1579         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Could you also share the R code used to get the second plot?

Comment: ...And give us the input data `X` to give context to why the R diagram "makes a lot more sense"

Comment: The R code has been added. Just use squareform(Y) in Matlab to get the X-matrix, but I can add it to the post too

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the answer now - if I use the **linkageold** function (found in the script for the current **linkage** function) I get the right result.